# In VS Code how can I put the "Show Opened Editors" action on a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: visual-studio-code, user-interface, fileopenpicker

In the three dots menu of each editor *group* I have the "Show Opened Editors" action:

[image]

This shows a selection list for all the editors *in the current group*. How can I put this action on a keyboard shortcut? I had a look for suitable command names (like `workBench.action.quickOpen`, but I could not find anything for *this specific* selection.

However there should be a command for this: after all clicking on the "Show Opened Editors" menu entry does it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using the `View: Show Editors in Active Group By Most Recently Used (workbench.action.showEditorsInActiveGroup)` command. You can edit it in 2 ways:

1. Open the `Keyboard Shortcuts` panel and search it by command name as seen in this [Keyboard Shortcuts Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INGzk.png). This command has no default keyboard shortcut so, need to change its keybinding with your shortcut. Then, when you use this shortcut it shows active opened editors:

2. You can place it from the `keybindings.json` file directly. Need to click the file icon `"Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)"` at the right top on the screenshot above. Then, you can add this command there by using these configurations:

```json
{
   "key": "Write your shortcut combination here",
   "command": "workbench.action.showEditorsInActiveGroup"
}
```

Hope, it's clear and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command: `workbench.explorer.openEditorsView.toggleVisibility`

In a keybinding:

```json
{
  "key": "alt+t",
  "command": "workbench.explorer.openEditorsView.toggleVisibility"
}
```

The first time you use it the view will be collapsed but it will remember the open/collapsed state afer that.